# Negative Decimals in Cassandra PHP-Driver by datastax

Tags: php, cassandra, cql

Weird problem: I can see negative decimals in the cqlsh... but when I retrieve the exact same row (by the exact same row key) in my php-script, negative decimals get corrupted to arbitrary positive values. This does not happen to rows with positiv decimals, they are read correctly.

```
$sql = "SELECT token(id) as token_id, id, latitude, longitude FROM items WHERE token(id) > ".$lastToken." LIMIT 100 ";

$statement = new \Cassandra\SimpleStatement($sql);
$future = $this->getSession()->executeAsync($statement);
$result = $future->get();
```

I can see the value for latitude in the output of the cql in cqlsh, which is -20.25476 as expected, but in the php-script the Decimal-Objects toDouble()-Method returns 1838.24568762834

Comment: I could not solve the problem, I had to abandon decimals.